# django - with transaction.atomic() context manager - catch exceptions

Tags: python, django, logging, django-orm, django-database

I'm trying to log database errors using the `transation.commit()` context manager.
This is the code chunk:

```
def _process_batch(_lower_limit, _upper_limit, step, **kwargs):
        skipped_rows_mapping = kwargs.pop('skipped_rows_mapping')
        form_errors = kwargs.pop('form_errors')
        process_rows_object_list = _process_rows(
            _lower_limit, _upper_limit, **process_rows_kwargs
        )
        try:
            with transaction.atomic():
                Transcript.objects.bulk_create(process_rows_object_list, batch_size=2000)
            if verbose:
                print('processed {} rows; {} transcripts created...'.format(
                    upper_limit, len(process_rows_object_list))
                )
                print_timestamp()

            # periodically log errors to logfiles
            for _key, _vals in skipped_rows_mapping.items():
                with open(_vals['logfile'], 'a+') as logfile:
                    _writer = csv.writer(logfile, delimiter=str('|'))
                    _writer.writerows(
                        [r + (_vals['msg'],) for r in _vals['lst']]
                    )
                    skipped_rows_mapping[_key]['lst'] = []
            if form_errors.keys():
                with open("/tmp/process_transcripts_with_temp_db_table_form_errors", 'a+') as log_file:
                    for _form_err, _rows_ in form_errors.items():
                        _writer = csv.writer(log_file, delimiter=str('|'))
                        _writer.writerows(
                            [_r + (_form_err,) for _r in _rows_]
                        )
                        form_errors[_form_err] = list()

        except (IntegrityError, DatabaseError) as db_exception:
            errors_list.append(
                ErrorDetails(
                    err_type=db_exception.__class__.__name__,
                    msg=db_exception.message, id_interval=(_lower_limit, _upper_limit)
                )
            )
        finally:
            _lower_limit = _upper_limit
            _upper_limit += step
            if _upper_limit > max_id:
                _upper_limit = max_id
            return _lower_limit, _upper_limit
```

However `IntegrityError` and `DatabaseError` are not catched, probably due to the `with transaction.atomic()` block that already handle the exceptions.

How I have to modify the code to catch and log those errors?

Comment: `transaction.atomic()` does not catch exceptions, it only rolls back the transaction when an exception occurs. If your `try` block doesn't catch any exceptions, it's because there is no exception in the first place.

Comment: ok, so the code is not wrote in the wrong way...
I'm just wondering how to debug this: this code process 10k rows at tine, and insert into db through a single bulk insert. 
Sometimes, an error occurs and those 10k entries are not inserted. Ay Idea on how to debug this? Maybe catching a generic `Exception` instead of the two db-specific ones?